# jQuery 3.x child selector

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

In jQuery 1.10.2 you could do [this.](http://api.jquery.com/child-selector/)

```
$("parent > child")
```

Now in jQuery 3.1.1 this doesn't work...

Get this error:

```
$("button[tooltip] ^ span")
jquery-3.1.1.min.js:2 Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: button[tooltip] ^ span
at Function.ga.error (jquery-3.1.1.min.js:2)
at ga.tokenize (jquery-3.1.1.min.js:2)
at ga.select (jquery-3.1.1.min.js:2)
at Function.ga [as find] (jquery-3.1.1.min.js:2)
at r.fn.init.find (jquery-3.1.1.min.js:2)
at new r.fn.init (jquery-3.1.1.min.js:2)
at r (jquery-3.1.1.min.js:2)
at <anonymous>:1:1
```

What is the correct way to select child in jQuery 3.x?

Comment: I didn't know it was depricated, but you might be able to replace it with .children()

Comment: `^` is not the same as `>`.  Are you confusing it with the [attribute starts with](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/) selector?  `>` is like the standard CSS direct descendant selector, I doubt they would remove it.

Answer (score 2):

```
 $('parent > child')
```

works perfectly well in jQuery and so does any other **valid CSS selector**.
And `$('parent ^ child')` is not one.

```js
console.log($("parent > child").attr('id'));
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>


<parent>
  <child id="foo"></child>
</parent>
```

`$("parent>[id^='f']")` is, though:

```js
console.log($("parent>[id^='f']").attr('id'));
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>


<parent>
  <child id="foo"></child>
</parent>
```